# Platform to test using Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

Just read about Cucumber from various sources. One source stated that Cucumber can only be used in testing Web Applications, other stated that Cucumber can be used for both Web Applications and Android, and the other one stated otherwise.

Which is the correct one? What platforms can we test using Cucumber? (ex. Web Application, Android, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber can be used both for web apps and mobile apps because essentially Cucumber is used to run an automated acceptance tests written in a behavior-driven development (BDD) style